# Error opening Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am unable to open Eclipse IDE. The error displayed is as below

[image]

Any idea what could be the reason? And how do I solve this??

**Note**: I ran CCleaner recently (any registry issue??) and I got error executing my open Eclispe project. On restarting I get this issue. Is re-installation going to help? Am going to do that and update result here. And I would really like to know what caused this for future precautions.

**Update**: Same error for new installation. But this time got error regarding lauching JVM and missing dlls so going to reinstall Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to understand what might be the exact problem , still giving it a shot.

Did you go through this URL http://michaelzanussi.com/?p=468

Appears to be the same issue , resetting JAVA_HOME and PATH solved the issue for him

Answer (score 1):

The authors of Eclipse strongly recommend manually updating the Eclipse.ini file to point directly to the JRE that you want to use rather than relying on Windows environment variables.

Also C:\Windows\System32 is a really strange place to find the Java Runtime Environment files, typically they wind up in C:\Program Files\Java or C:\Program Files (x86)\Java.